# agrupar los datos de una list<string> c#

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista de element que contiene información

```
  {
    "Folio": 127105,
    "FechaReserva": "2019-10-28T00:00:00",
    "FechaActual": "2019-11-05T07:00:04.353",
    "Fe_llegada": "16/12/2019",
    "Fe_salida": "19/12/2019",
    "MonedaBase": "mxn",
    "Fecha_limitecancelacion": "2019-12-14T00:00:00",
    "nombredestino": "Cancún",
    "Hotelplan": "Todo Incluido",
    "Habitacion": "Estándar",
    "FechaLlegada": "Diciembre",
    "DescripcionServicio": "Hotel Aquamarina Beach Cancún - Estándar-Todo Incluido",
    "Hotel": "Hotel Aquamarina Beach Cancún",
    "FechaServicio": "16 de Diciembre 19 al 19 de Diciembre 19",
    "categoria": 4,
    "Numero_hab": 1
  },
```

quiero recuperar el valor del atributo nombredestino de todos los elementos que contiene mi primera lista y almacenarlo en otra list

```
        List<Destino> jaa = (from item in rest group item by item.nombredestino into x
               select new Destino 
               {
                   Nombre = x.ToString(),
               }).ToList();
```

he intentado esto pero no he logrado, ya que al analizar el contendio de la lista jaa, el nombre aparece de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres recuperar una lista de una propiedad agrupando deberia ser

```
List<Destino> jaa = (from item in rest 
                        group item by item.nombredestino into x
                       select new Destino 
                       {
                           Nombre = x.Key,
                       }).ToList();
```

estas agrupando por esa propiedad por eso usas el `Key`

[Agrupar los resultados de consultas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Comment: Excelente muchas garcias sin duda esta es la solución que buscaba